# Nodejs GPU.js slower using GPU than using CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, gpgpu

I have run a benchmark to compare the use of CPU and GPU in nodejs with GPU.js. The NVidia icon shows GPU use in the first console timer, but it is slower than the CPU (second timer).

```
const {GPU} = require('gpu.js');
const gpu = new GPU();

const multiplyMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(a, b) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        sum += a[this.thread.y][i] * b[i][this.thread.x];
    }
    return sum;
}).setOutput([512, 512]);

var a = [];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    a.push([]);
    b.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        a[i].push(1);
        b[i].push(-1);
    }
}

console.time("gpu");
const c = multiplyMatrix(a, b);
console.timeEnd("gpu"); //2148ms

console.time("cpu");
var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    d.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let k = 0; k < 512; k++) {
            sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
        
        d[i].push(sum);
    }
}
console.timeEnd("cpu"); //710ms
```

Am I doing something clearly wrong?

Comment: No expert here, but from what I understand GPU has big gains when calculations are kept parallel.  `sum +=` is not, so one idea is use another array to store the loop calls, and calculate the sum from this array.

Comment: Wow! I took this example from GPU.js site, https://gpu.rocks. I thought it would run in parallel for each pair (i, j)

Comment: You have a slow GPU or a fast CPU, or both. I have a 1070 and get ~80ms vs 350ms on the CPU.

Comment: Not sure, if it is on gpu.js, then I would expect it knows how to optimise  += & **.   Running your code on my machine I get  44ms & 239ms.  So GPU is running about 6 times faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this isn't the way to benchmarking CPU vs GPU

1. the GPU got warmup time so if you really want to benchmark compare both of them on a 1000 execution  and not single execution
2. GPU won't always be faster it depends on the task and the GPU RAM Size
3. and finally as Keith Mention at the comment gpu works better then cpu in parallel small task and large batches

Comment: Yes, I think your spot on here.   I just re-done Op's example but did 100 iterations, and GPU 719ms & CPU 26555.  So 37 times faster for GPU.  Maybe the OP's warm up time has a big effect on his hardware setup.

Comment: OK, got the 1000 runs and the GPU became faster. But I still cannot understand how to make my kernel function run in parallel. Or is it already parallel? How to check for it?

Comment: download nvidia-smi  it supplies a command-line tool that can show you how many cores use in each process

Comment: Great! Now everything makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Starting from 1024 on the matrix dimension, the GPU is performing better, so parallel gains are compensating warmup.